# Oracle Forms 6i Do You Want To Save Changes Message

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a form that contains several data blocks, all the fields are bind to the database by setting their properties to the database column name. All the items on each block are displayed on one canvas.

The items on the form contain personal data, however information like the customers phone numbers and addresses are stored on separate tables on a one to many mapping and is linked by the customer number, it takes into consideration the customer can have many phone numbers and many addresses.

The biggest problem here is when the user user is in query mode and has entered information on each block when they try to leave a block they get a message asking them 'Do You Want To Save Changes'. This happens for each block. So this message comes up several times.

What i am trying to achieve is this message should be suppressed so the user is asked this only once. I know once the user answers yes i can do_commit on each block to make changes save. However i have no control over this message and i would like to know the best way to structure an application to avoid this.

Comment: Try to add trigger KEY-EXIT with condition exit_form(no_validate);

Comment: but i do not want to exit the application i want to continue entering data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to trigger where you execute_query or do commit something like this.

```
:SYSTEM.MESSAGE_LEVEL := '25';
COMMIT;
:SYSTEM.MESSAGE_LEVEL := '0';
```

This suppress system messages. You did not write what trigger do you use in leaving block.